# Creating a subset array

Tags: r

all.

Long story short:

I have a dataset with over 60000 entries.

One variable is based on where the individual is from (location), with about 10 different categories.  Another is overall satisfaction, out of a score of 1 to 10.

However, all of the categories contain either the word Rural, or the word Urban.

What I would like to do is to compare the overall mean of all cases that contain the word Rural in the location variable, and all cases that contain the word Urban in the location variable.

I have used a work-around, which is just to create an additional column in the initial dataset in Excel that finds the word Rural or Urban in the location column and returns either Rural or Urban depending what is found, but I'm sure there must be a way to do this strictly using R.

Is this possible?  Thank you!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- data.frame(
  loc=sample(c(paste0("Rural",LETTERS[1:5]),paste0(LETTERS[10:14],"Urban")),
    100,replace=TRUE),
  xx=rnorm(100))
```

Now it sounds like you want `grepl()` to grep for your keywords, and `by()` to calculate means *by* keyword:

```
> with(foo,by(xx,grepl("Urban",loc),mean))
grepl("Urban", loc): FALSE
[1] -0.07220176
-------------------------------
grepl("Urban", loc): TRUE
[1] 0.04159463
```

Or maybe you actually want a t-test:

```
> with(foo,t.test(xx~grepl("Urban",loc)))

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  xx by grepl("Urban", loc)
t = -0.60245, df = 97.076, p-value = 0.5483
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4886860  0.2610932
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
        -0.07220176          0.04159463
```